# Where to set Path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, git, heroku, environment-variables

I am trying to get my first rails app on heroku, and am getting errors related to not being able to find git. Following different questions and answers lead me to the instructions to set the PATH environment variable to run git under cmd on windows with rails, which will apparently resolve the issue.

The original answer leading me to this is here - 
[How to run Ruby and GIT commands in one place on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426347/how-to-run-ruby-and-git-commands-in-one-place-on-windows)

However, I can't figure out where/how to set the PATH environment variable, as instructed. 
I can't seem to find a file in my rails app or ruby directory.

Am i going about this all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you actually install git? Did you read the official [Getting Started with Heroku on Windows](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/windows)?

Comment: sorry for the late response Michael, I've been running git all along, but somehow the page I was following on the Heroku site wasn't the one you sent. I'm not sure if I'm in better shape now, following the page you recommended, i've uploaded my ssh key to heroku, but when I try to clone my repository to heroku, it says I'm trying to clone an empty repository. I run git from the a separate git bash, not from a regular cmd window, so not sure if that is causing the issue.

Comment: If you never uploaded you site, it's normal the clone doesn't work. But if the `heroku` and `git` commands work, you should be able to use heroku normally: create a local repository with your Rails app and push it. See http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/quickstart