# Command-line Git on Windows

Tags: windows, git, command-line

I have installed msysGit 1.7.10 on my Windows 7 machine.
What I need to know is if I can still use Git from command line?

When I try the `git` command in the command line right now I see:

> 'git' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Is there any way I can enable the Git command line?

Comment: Set your `PATH` environment variable to point to where msysgit's bin is.

Comment: @birryree thanks. I re-installed with Git Bash option and it seemed to work fine.

Comment: This answer fills in the details -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426347/how-to-run-ruby-and-git-commands-in-one-place-on-windows

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As @birryree said, add msysgit's binary to your PATH, or use Git Bash (installed with msysgit as far as I remember) which is better than Windows' console and similar to the Unix one.

Comment: Note that Git bash does not support non-ASCII characters. This might not be an issue, but the OP should be warned anyway.

Answer (score 88):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding the `/bin` directory location to the PATH Environment Variable.

1. Search for the file location where Git was installed, mine is `C:\Users\(My UserName)\AppData\Local\GitHub`. It may also be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git`
2. Once you have the location of Git you should see a `/bin` sub-folder. It may be in a PortableGit folder (mine is
   `PortableGit_015aa71ef18c047ce8509ffb2f9e4bb0e3e73f13`). Copy this path.
3. Go to Control Panel > System > System Protection > Advanced > Environment Variables
4. Choose PATH, click edit and paste the bin path there. If there are already any values in your PATH paste your Git path at the end separated with a semi-colon.

Now you can access Git command from CMD.

Comment: By doing this, you also put other Unix commands on your path (e.g., there may be a conflict between Windows `find` and Unix `find`). This *is* a good answer, and it works for me. Just be forewarned.

Comment: This solves the problem, but the PortableGit_ directory will change names, because of the hash code, so I have to modify the PATH environment, how to solve this problem?

Comment: mine happened to be C:\Program Files\Git\bin

Answer (score 23):

These instructions worked for a Windows 8 with a msysgit/TortoiseGit installation, but should be applicable for other types of git installations on Windows.

- Go to **Control Panel\System and Security\System**
- Click on **Advanced System Settings** on the left which opens System Properties.
- Click on the **Advanced Tab**
- Click on the **Environment
  Variables** button at the bottom of the dialog box.
- Edit the **System
  Variable** called **PATH**.
- Append these two paths to the list of existing paths already present in the system variable. The tricky part was two paths were required. These paths may vary for your PC. `;C:\msysgit\bin\;C:\msysgit\mingw\bin\`
- Close the CMD prompt window if it is open already. CMD needs to restart to get the updated Path variable.
- Try typing **git** in the command line, you should see a list of the git commands scroll down the screen.

Answer (score 14):

**In windows 8.1**, setting the PATH Environment Variable to Git's `bin` directory didn't work for me. Instead, I had to use the `cmd` directory `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd`.

Credit to @VonC [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426347/how-to-run-ruby-and-git-commands-in-one-place-on-windows)

Answer (score 2):

For me, I'm using Windows 10, @andrew-marshall's instructions worked (Thanks!) except that `git.exe` was within a `cmd` directory within `PortableGit...`, not `bin`, so I had to put `\cmd` on the end of the path I added to `PATH`. Thought I would post this here in case anyone else hits the same issue. You can tell it works once `git` in a new Command Prompt window returns command usage info and not an error.

Answer (score 1):

In the latest version (v2.19 for Windows when I'm writing), if you choose the option "Use git in Windows command prompt" (or sth similar, please read the options carefully when you install git), you should be able to use git commands in windows command prompt or windows powershell without any additional setting. Just remember to restart the command line tool after you install git.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed GitHubDesktop in Windows 10, then press Ctrl + '. 
 or in the menu go to Repository>Open in command prompt.

In case git is not installed in your machine, you should get a prompt to install git.(I came to know from this that GitHubDesktop and git are different applications). Install git, close your command prompt and open it again.

You can test your installation by typing in git at the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

You can install [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/). It's like apt-get in Linux, you can install using the command line. Run Command Prompt as Administrator and type `choco install git` and you'll be able to install git devoted to the command line.

Answer (score 0):

as of now, with win 1909 and using Git-2.24.0.2-64-bit installer the process is very friendly towards user configuration. Seems like the earlier problems may now be catered for.