# Enabling git in Windows 10 command line

Tags: windows, git, powershell, github, command-line

I cannot seem to make git work from my native Windows command line.
I have tried PowerShell, I have the path to the git bin in my Environment Variables, but it is still giving me a "`command not found`" when I type `git`.  I have looked at the solutions
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11000869/command-line-git-on-windows), and none of them work for me.
I don't have a `C:/Program Files/git folder (or Program Files(x86))`.

I can make command line git work if I open up the git desktop app and then use the "open a terminal with git enabled" option from there.

That is all well and good, except that opening the desktop app takes forever on my laptop, and I would prefer to be able to just whip out the command line to pull my code.

I am open to reinstalling git and following specific instructions, or installing a more workable version of git, if anyone has suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried cgwin?  http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=fw2eR0_Dfyw

Comment: Personally, I'd suggest you install "Git Bash" when you install git on windows (It's an option during the install).  It installs a Mingw32 git command-line which emulates the linux command line.  You can still traverse your drives and everything, but the directory arguments play better with git (since it wasn't really built for windows).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Simply uncompress the latest [git for windows release](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) portable archive (like [PortableGit-2.7.2-64-bit.7z.exe](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/download/v2.7.2.windows.1/PortableGit-2.7.2-64-bit.7z.exe)) anywhere you want and add to your PATH:

```
 c:\path\to\git;c:\path\to\git\bin;c:\path\to\git\usr\bin;c:\path\to\git\mingw64\bin
```

You will get `git-bash.exe` (recent 4.3+ bash [based on msys2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35099458/6309)), but also 200+ unix commands right in your regular CMD shell.