# How to change from MinTTY to Windows 10 default console in Git Bash?

Tags: bash, git, git-bash, mintty

I am using Windows 10.
I have Git Bash (from Git 2.20.1) installed with configuration of using MinTTY as terminal emulator.
I can see that following entry in Git-2.20.1/etc/install-options.txt
`Bash Terminal Option: MinTT`
This means when I start `git-bash` it uses MinTTY as terminal - one can see this by right clicking on the title bar of git-bash window.

Now I have to switch to windows default console. When I say "switch" I mean when I start `git-bash` I expect it to use windows console - I should be able to confirm this by right clicking on the title bar of git-bash window.

Below link explains the difference between MinTTY and Windows console - https://willi.am/blog/2016/08/08/docker-for-windows-interactive-sessions-in-mintty-git-bash/

However I cant find any config or mechanism to change this. (Changing install-options.txt with `Bash Terminal Option: ConHost` does not have any effect)
And I cant reinstall it as it has came via my organizations packaging system.

Is there any config anyone knows which I am missing?

Appreciate help - Many Thanks !

Comment: Can't say for sure but I think instead you need to do this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34555806/791430

Comment: @PreetamPalwe : What do you mean by _switching_ here? Mintty is a terminal program, which you start explicitly. The windows console (I guess you mean by this what you get on windows when you do a Windows+R key and then start the command `cmd`) is also explicitly started by you. What kind of switching do you need, if you can decide which one you want to run?

Comment: @user1934428 - I have improved my question to answer your queries - thanks !

Comment: Do you mean when you double click `git-bash.exe`, you get mintty terminal, but you want a Windows 10 default console ?

Comment: @PreetamPalwe : Why don't you do it the other way round: Start any terminal you like, and from within run your bash shell manually? BTW, your question is not really about programming and hence off-topic here. You better ask this at, say, [Superuser](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Philippe - yes - exactly (Not necessarily double click - you can start git-bash via command line as well. run cmd -> goto git installation folder -> run git-bash

Comment: @user1934428 - yes - I am already running my shell script via bash. I started bash by directly running it from windows cmd.exe. (E.g. run cmd -> goto git installation folder \bin -> run bash)

Comment: So you can run bash from the Windows console. Where is the problem then?

Comment: The problem is - if I run git-bash then I get mintty and I wanted windows console :)

Answer (score 0):

This switch is a part of git-bash.exe binary. It's only being edited by Git Windows installer hook named edit-git-bash.

You could compile and run edit-git-bash.

Or reinstall Git entirely (simpler)

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the same **Git for Windows** version on another windows machine, choose **"Use Windows default console window"** during installation.

Copy **C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe** from another machine to your organization's computer (if movement of binary files is restricted, try to encode it with base64, copy and decode).

At your organization's computer copy **C:\Program Files\Git** to Desktop folder  and replace **Desktop\Git\git-bash.exe** with **git-bash.exe** from another machine.

Now you can use **git bash with MinTTY(MSYS2)** from *C:\Program Files\Git* and **git bash with Windows default console** from *Desktop\Git* at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Windows shortcut with these configurations:

- Target: `C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe /c "bash --login -i"`
- Start in: `%userprofile%`
- Change icon to: `C:\Program Files\Git\git-bash.exe`

You can move the Windows shortcut to the Start Menu: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`. Then you can access it from the Start Menu.

This will open Git Bash using the Windows Terminal. The Windows Terminal in Windows 10/11 is much improved over the classic Windows Command Prompt.