# How can I add git to the ruby command line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows, git, command-line

I am looking to access git commands from the Ruby command line in Windows 10 however when I attempt to run a git command I get a "git is not recognized" error. I can call git commands from the standard command line without any problems. I have updated my paths to include C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\ and C:\Program Files\Git\bin\ however this has not resolved the error. Any other suggestions of how to solve this?

Comment: What is _the Ruby command line_? Do you mean _irb_ or the _rails console_ or something different?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set your `PATH` to git correctly. By default, git should already be configured to `PATH` automatically. Go [to this link](https://git-scm.com/) and download the correct version for your system and then install it. Afterwards, open the windows terminal and everything should work.

This may help you out: [How to run Ruby and GIT commands in one place on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3426347/how-to-run-ruby-and-git-commands-in-one-place-on-windows)